# Letters/Characters on iPhone Swapping Position

Tags: iphone, character, letters

A website we have recently built is behaving rather oddly on iPhones - certain letters in a blog post are displaying in the wrong order.

They appear as intended on desktops and Android devices, but on iPhones the letters F and L are swapping position, so the word "Life" reads as "Lfie".

I have no idea where to start with this one, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

You can see an example here:

http://breadandoysters.com/sylvia-plath/

Comment: I am not seeing this problem with iOS 9.3, but I do see it on iOS 10. So there is your starting point :)

Comment: I have researched your problem. On my Iphone i only get it with safari and chrome. Further more on my macbook, i don't get the problem in chrome but in safari it the fault is there again. 

An other thing is that if you copy the word "Ffities" from your site and you copy it in a text editor, the word is spelled right as Fifties!

I wish you good luck.

Comment: I also noticed that letters are not swapped, "if" is replaced by single character "fi", not sure what the name is. It might some weird autocorrect thing or something to do with the wordpress theme you are using. I have no experience with wordpress or its themes, but maybe there is some setting you can turn on/off that would stop this replacing

Answer (score 0):

So after Lope's suggestion of a theme issue we went down that route and eventually discovered that it was a problem with the font that was being used. The font was Rubik - a Google font. Thanks for suggestions.